# JavaScript and HTML Form 'Bank'

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to be able to have a form that takes a 'deposit' or 'withdraw' and will add or subtract for a variable. Then, I would like to be able to put that variable in the webpage, and be able to keep it for a day or two. I do not know what is wrong with my code at this point.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- hide this script from old browsers
    //Bank 
    var bank = 0;
    var bank_name = "The Bank of Pacycephalosaurus";
    var bank_interestPolicy = 0;
    var bank_interestPolicy_interestAmount = 2;
    var bank_ineterestPolicy_interest = function (amount) {
        var interestGain = bank_contents_money / bank_interestPolicy_interestAmount;
        var bank_contents_money = bank_contents_money + interestGain;
    };

    var bank_contents = 0;
    var bank_contents_money = 0;
    var bank_contents_items = "None";
    var bank_withdrawAmount = "0";
    var bank_depositAmount = "0";
    var bank_withdraw = function (amount) {
        //Check if there is money
        if (bank_contents_money < amount) {
            alert("Withdraw DENIED Insufficient Funds");
        } else {
            alert("Sufficient Funds ... Transfering Funds ...");
            var transPlace = confirm("Transfer funds to " + wallet_name + "?");
            if (transPlace === false) {
                alert("Transfer Location Unknown :: 404 Not Found :: Please Try Again");
            } else {
                alert("Transfering Funds ... Transfer Succesful!");
                form.bank_money.value = bank_contents_money - amount;
                wallet_money = wallet_money + amount;
            }
        }
    };
    var bank_deposit = function (amount) {
        //Check if there is money
        if (wallet_money < amount) {
            alert("Deposit DENIED Insufficient Funds");
        } else {
            alert("Sufficient Funds ... Transfering Funds ...");
            var transPlace = confirm("Transfer funds to " + bank_name + "?");
            if (transPlace === false) {
                alert("Transfer Location Unknown :: 404 Not Found :: Please Try Again");
            } else {
                alert("Transfering Funds ... Transfer Succesful!");
                alert("The Amount: " + amount);
                form.bank_money.value = bank.contents_money + amount;
                bank_contents_money = bank.contents_money + amount;
                alert("The Amount: " + amount);
                bank_opening(amount);
            }
        }
    };
    var bank_opening = function (money) {
        alert("You have $" + bank_contents_money + " in your bank.");
        $.cookie("bankMoney", money, {
            expires: 1
        });
        alert($.cookie("example"));
    };

    var wallet = 0;
    var wallet_name = "Wallet of You!";
    var wallet_money = 0;
    bank_opening();
// done hiding from old browsers -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h2>Bamk</h2>
Enter a number to withdraw or deposit: 
<INPUT NAME="deposit" VALUE="0" MAXLENGTH="15" SIZE=15>
  <p>
<INPUT NAME="depos" VALUE="Deposit" TYPE=BUTTON 
onClick=bank_deposit(deposit.form)>
<p>
  <p>
<INPUT NAME="withd" VALUE="Withdraw" TYPE=BUTTON 
onClick=bank_withdraw(this.form)>
<p>
The amount in a bank is: 
<INPUT NAME="bank_contents_money" READONLY SIZE=15>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's happening? Or maybe what's not happening?

Comment: you trying to keep "data" in browser for a day or two?

Comment: First Question: I can't get it too display the 'bank_contents_money' in on the HTML page, I think that it is something with the HTML Form.
Second Question: I'm trying to keep data in the browser with a cookie (or something) so that every time the page (re)loads it does not start over.